# Return parsedobject after asyncronous post request objective-c IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, delegates, request

I am trying to get a parsed object from a JSON response and use in a method, When I do that normally, I can use the parsedObject after this method 
[self.delegate requestJSONFinishedWithParsedObject:parsedObject]; that I use, but now I want this parsedObject where I want. I mean calling a method and have the object in the return.

Something like this :

NSDictionary *parsedObject = [self.delegate responseJsonDictionary]; 
To use it in the class where I need it.

My problem is that I have a `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *projectsArray;` and I want to fullfil this property before I use it. I am creating a dynamic menu with items from a JSON but when the data from the JSON is in self.projectsArray My menu is already created and the objects of the json doesnt appear.

I am using this slide menu: https://github.com/andrewroycarter/SlideViewController

I use this class to manage all the requests and it works perfectly.

RequestJSON.m

```
-(void) requestWithURL:(NSDictionary *)jsonDictionary :(NSString*)myURL :(NSString *)method
{


    NSURL *thisURL = [NSURL URLWithString:myURL];


    NSString *__jsonString;
    NSData *__jsonData;
    if([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:jsonDictionary])
    {
        __jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDictionary options:0 error:nil];
        __jsonString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:__jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }



    // Be sure to properly escape your url string.
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:thisURL];
    [request setHTTPMethod:method];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:@"Carlos" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User"];

    if([method isEqual: @"POST"]){
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [__jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setHTTPBody: __jsonData];

    }
    NSLog(@"llega= asdasdasd %@, %@, %@",method,jsonDictionary,myURL);

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];


}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{

    //INicializo variable NSMutableData
    self.myConnectionData= [NSMutableData data];


    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    NSDictionary *myResponse = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    myResponse=[httpResponse allHeaderFields];
    statusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];

}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.myConnectionData appendData:data];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [self.delegate requestJSONFailed];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    NSError *thisError;


    NSDictionary *parsedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myConnectionData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&thisError];

    [self.delegate requestJSONFinishedWithParsedObject:parsedObject];
}

@end
```

RequestJSON.h

```
@protocol RequestJSONDelegate;

@interface RequestJSON : NSObject
{
    NSInteger statusCode;

}

@property (nonatomic,assign) id <RequestJSONDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableData *myConnectionData;

-(void) requestWithURL:(NSDictionary *) params:(NSString*)myURL :(NSString *)method;
-(void) requestForLogin:(NSString*)myURL :(NSString*)method :(NSString*)pass;

@end


@protocol RequestJSONDelegate

-(void) requestJSONFinishedWithParsedObject:(NSDictionary*)parsedObject;

-(void) requestJSONFailed;

@end
```

In the other classes where I Want to get this data I use this methods

```
-(void) requestJSONFinishedWithParsedObject:(NSDictionary *)parsedObject{

    NSArray  *projectsObjectArray = [parsedObject objectForKey:@"projects"];
}

-(void) requestJSONFailed{}
```

And to start the request I use this in my main class.

example.m

```
 RequestJSON *requestJSON = [ [RequestJSON alloc] init];
    [requestJSON requestWithURL:(NSDictionary *) params:url :method];
    [requestJSON setDelegate:self];
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

your requests are asynchronous , so you should handle the case that the content of your menu is not yet ready and show some loading UI like an activity indicator if the data are not yet ready and show an error, for example using an alertView, in case the request fail...

so when you create your UIViewController in the viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear, or where is better for your application you should check if you have already the data to display, if not display your loading UI (I hope you are using some kind of cache and not requesting those data all the times)

implementing your protocol

if you have a success

```
- (void)requestJSONFinishedWithParsedObject:(NSDictionary *)parsedObject {

    //remove the loading UI
    [self removeLoadingView]; // your custom method to remove the loading UI

    // populate your data source and reload the content
    self.projectsArray = [parsedObject objectForKey:@"projects"];

    // this in case you are using a tableview for your menu
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

in case of failure

```
- (void)requestJSONFailed {

    //remove the loading UI
    [self removeLoadingView]; // your custom method to remove the loading UI

    // show an error feedback like an alertview
    [self showError]; // your custom method to display errors
}
```

this could be a way to handle the loading, I don't suggest you to use synchronous request, this will stop your UI until the request is finished with a very bad user experience

Comment: Hi Manu, I've already done what you said, even I have put more [_tableView reloadData ] in my code. The problem is when I try to use the array for my section, it is still empty. I'm using this menu [link](https://github.com/andrewroycarter/SlideViewController) I create a new section in MySlideViewController.m  when I use projectsArray is empty but when I make a log in `- (void)requestJSONFinishedWithParsedObject:(NSDictionary *)parsedObject ` self.projectsArray its full.. Thank you

Comment: Very strange... first try to locate the problem, I suggest you to make a test, without any remote request, initialize your array with the data that your viewController expect to works, and go step by step in UITableView delegate methods checking that everything is ok. After that you did it check in your method - (void)requestJSONFinishedWithParsedObject:(NSDictionary *)parsedObject that the received data has the expected format

Comment: I did that too. if I create an array it works. the problem is that I receive information in the requestJSONFinishedWithPasedObject method and if I fulfill the array with the information there, array is empty in the first mthod. the problem is that I create the section before the self.projectArray is full.. and even reloading tableview I cant watch this data.

Comment: If you are 100% sure that the data from your request are correct and you are calling reloadData after you have assigned the projectsArray, be sure that, you are updating the tableview in the main thread,for exaple dispatching_asynch on the main_queue the reloadData method, and that the UITableView delegate methods are celled after the reloadData and you are returning the correct number of rows and sections. Could you pls post yours - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView and 
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section